# Select Box selecting next index value in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am getting dynamic list from angular js using ng-repeat. Here my requirement is I am unable to select dropdown with up and down arrows. For that I am Using Bootstrap select picker. It is working fine for first time select, But when try to select the same second time it is selecting the next index which I have selected.

**Eg:-** If I select 1 it is selecting 2.

I used the following to achive this functionality.

```
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.10.0/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.10.0/css/bootstrap-select.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

**AngularJS::**

```
    <select class="form-control selectpicker" selectpicker data-live-search="true" ng-model="subapp"  ng-change="getSubApplicationDetails(subapp)" >
          <option class="small-font" value='0'>--seleccionar--</option> 
         <option class="small-font" ng-repeat="subapp in subapplicationList track by $index" data-select-watcher data-last="{{$last}}" value="{{subapp}}" ><a>{{subapp.ID}}-{{subapp.DESCRIPCION}}</a></option>
    </select>
```

Comment: can you provide a more detailed explanation of your problem

Comment: I am using bootstrap selectpicker with angular js.when I am selecting one option first time displying correctly,next time onwards selecting next option i.e index 1 selected but displaying index 2 value.

Comment: hi tried your code and its working fine im getting the subapp value when i select except on your 0 index which is outputing 0.

Comment: at the first time selection its working fine, but the second time not working

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh');
```

You need to refresh the selectpicker every onchange event.

**HTML:-**

```
<select class="form-control selectpicker" selectpicker data-live-search="true" ng-model="subapp"  ng-change="getSubApplicationDetails(subapp)" >
          <option class="small-font" value='0'>--seleccionar--</option> 
         <option class="small-font" ng-repeat="subapp in subapplicationList track by $index" data-select-watcher data-last="{{$last}}" value="{{subapp}}" ><a>{{subapp.ID}}-{{subapp.DESCRIPCION}}</a></option>
    </select>
```

**AngularJS:-**

```
function getSubApplicationDetails(value)
{
   $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh');
    alert(value);
    ......
    ......
}
```